# Pandas (Python) get a DataFrame row after grouping by MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

```
         id  account_id         phone        created_dttm
0  18391122           3  +72222222222 2020-11-20 14:05:45
1  18391123           3  +72222222222 2020-11-21 15:31:27
2  18420891           2  +73333333333 2020-11-21 07:46:19
```

I want to group entries by `account_id` and `phone` and get a single entry from each group with the highest value of `created_dttm`. After that I want to get `id` by `account_id` and `phone`.

Currently I'm using the following code to get a corresponding DataFrame:

```py
grouped = df \
    .sort_values('created_dttm', ascending=False) \
    .groupby(['account_id', 'phone'], sort=False) \
    .first()
```

But then when I try to get a row by `account_id` and `phone` I have the following error:

```py
>>> grouped[[3, '+72222222222']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3030, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1266, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1308, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index([3, '+72222222222'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: MultiIndex keys are tuples `grouped.loc[(3, '+72222222222')]`, not lists (also need `.loc` to select along the Index, not columns)

Comment: `df.sort_values('created_dttm').drop_duplicates(['account_id', 'phone'], keep='last')`